# jQuery simple slideshow creates long pauses

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Here is this simple slideshow I'm using:

```
function slideShow(){
var current = $('#animation .show');
var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.parent().children(':first');
current.removeClass('show');
next.addClass('show');
setTimeout(slideShow, 500);
} 



$(document).ready(function() {
   slideShow();
 });
```

It works but it creates long pauses between images...Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
this is the HTML code,I guess pauses was the wrong word, what I want to achieve is every image is displayed immediately after the other, right now I have a small gap that nothing is displayed.

```
<div id="animation">
<img alt="graphic" class="show" src="files/animation_img/GRAPHIC.jpg" />
<img alt="design" src="files/animation_img/DESIGN.jpg" />
<img alt="etc" src="files/animation_img/ETC.jpg" />
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#animation  img
    {
    position:fixed;
    top:400px;
    left:700px;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    }
```

Comment: I think your code isn't working properly. According to your code, your images would zip by with less that 0.5 seconds per image!!

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzUqG/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating that your code works just fine.

Comment: can you post the HTML?  And the CSS?  Is your version of this really showing *all* the things in the "animation" element?

Comment: Maybe that your images are huge. They need to load to be shown.

Comment: I commented out the line //current.removeClass('show'); and images load way faster but it just loops once and then it stops!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function slideShow(){
    var current = $('#animation .show');
    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.parent().children(':first');
    current.removeClass('show');
    next.addClass('show');
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(slideShow, 500)
});
```

Comment: There's not really anything wrong with setting up a timeout handler the what the OP does it. It's not really recursive because the next call to the function will happen long after the first call has returned; thus at any point there will only be one active invocation of the function.

Comment: @experimentX, I removed my vote earlier. You're using setInterval and not timeout. Your suggestion is valid :)

Comment: @JophP it seems to me that @Pointy is valid too ... but I don't prefer to use this programmatic structure.

Comment: @experimentX the code as posted in the question works just fine - see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zzUqG/

Comment: @experimentX well it's certainly true that what you posted is OK too - there are reasons to do it both ways; in this case it's so simple that either one should work fine.   (And in fact, the OP code **does** work so I don't know what's going on here :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know that there is nothing wrong with the code but for some reason it takes some time to display a new image, maybe if I do hide() instead of removeClass() ?

Comment: @rabidmachine9 i can you do without adding/removing class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257226/toggle-two-images-by-fading/5257472#5257472 just finding the no children ... you know